# vscode attach debugger not working with preLaunchTask

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

VScode 1.70.2 , we have the following launch.json

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "address": "localhost",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/app",
       "preLaunchTask": "docker-compose-debug",
      "skipFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

We wish to run docker-compose to start the containers before attaching with the following task, however the debugger does not attach. If we launch the containers manually and then attach it works fine

```
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "docker-compose-debug",
      "type": "docker-compose",
      "dockerCompose": {
        "up": {
          "detached": false,
          "build": true,
          "services": ["mysql", "phone"]
        },
        "files": ["${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose-dev.yml"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone say what we are missing

Answer (score 1):

By setting the detached property to true it works

```
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "docker-compose-debug",
      "type": "docker-compose",
      "dockerCompose": {
        "up": {
          "detached": true,
          "build": true,
          "services": ["mysql", "phone"]
        },
        "files": ["${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose-dev.yml"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```